# How to notify GUI changes with INotifyPropertyChanged immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have an ObservableCollection binded to a Datagrid on my view, each element has a Bool property `IsSelected` binded to a `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` until here everything Works as a MVVM must. But my problem is that `INotifyPropertyChanged` doesn't trigger just after the user changes my `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`, it triggers only when it loses focus.

What can I do to force the grid to notify of the change immediately, not when the column loses the focus?

I was trying setting

```
NotifyOnSourceUpdated=true
NotifyOnTargetUpdated=true
```

this is my column

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="{x:Static resources:Labels.TESORERIA_AplicarTodo}"
                        Binding="{Binding Path=Seleccionado,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set **UpdateSourceTrigger**  to *PropertyChanged* on your binding.

```
UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the Binding like

```
Binding="{Binding Path=Seleccionado,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"
```